# Do i need models.py even for ready made mysql databases?

Tags: django, django-models

I spin up a django project. Afterwards, i didn't write models.py but instead I created a database from MySQL command line(independent from django) and created three tables with required columns. Finally i connected my django app with that database successfully. I applied migrations. But now i am confused do i need to write models.py with every field name as in column?

I remember implementing a basic project in which i did write models.py and created database using "python manage.py shell" and then put values using 
 "from polls.models import Choice, Question"? How do i put data now initially and then using python on some action from UI?

Comment: You can use [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) to let Django create the models for you. Although it still might require some finetuning.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem means i do need models.py. Thanks. What if i write equivalent code in models.pt myself? Will it work or break?

Comment: you can write it yourself, but likely should write `managed = False` in the meta, to avoid that Django will construct the tables itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Do i need `models.py` even for ready made mysql databases?

You do not *need* to construct models. Some (small) webservers are even completely *stateless*, and thus do not use a database. But a large part of how Django can help you is based on models.

You can write your own queries, forms, etc. But often by using a `ModelForm`, Django can for example remove a large amount of boilerplate code. It will make it furthermore less likely that there are mistakes in your code. So although not strictly necessary, the models are usually a keystone in how Django can help you.

You can use the [**`inspectdb`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) command to inspect the database, and let Django "sketch" the models for you. Usually you will have still some work. Since Django can, for example, not derive that a field is an `EmailField`, since both a `CharField` and `EmailField` look exactly the same at the database side.

You do not need to use `inspectdb` however. You can construct your own models. If you create your own models, but these exist already at the database side, you might want to set [**`managed = False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#managed) in the `Meta` of your model, to prevent Django from constructing migrations.